# How to receive JSON from POST?

Tags: laravel

I receive JSON from Vue.JS client via REST Api, and I'd like to get data using Eloquent, but it doesn't work. It's not blade and not standard form-submit data, I receive JSON Api from client, single-page application.

This is the JSON, addressed to route '/order' from client, method POST:

```
    {
        "name": "John",
        "phone": "+7 794 910 5708",
        "email": "example@gmail.com"
    }
```

The route is:

```
Route::post('/order','OrderController@order');
```

In a Controller I try to do that:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Request;
    use App\Data;

    class OrderController extends Controller
    {
        public function order()
        {
            $input = Request::all();
            $data = new Data;
            $data->name = $input['name'];
            $data->phone = $input['phone'];
            $data->save();
            return response()->json(['result' => '200 OK'], 200);
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens. What is the right syntax to receive data from REST Api?

Comment: Have you tried debugging by dumping out the request data that you receive? For example can you share what you get when you do `dd(request()->all());`? Put this in your order function as a first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some changes as per below:

In controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Data;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function order(Request $request)
    {
        $post = $request->all();

        $data = Data::create($post);

        if($data){
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Data has been inserted!']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Data not inserted, Something went wrong!']);        
        }
    }
}
```